# How to get max value of a column based on value of another column?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my Database I have a table called `ARTICLES`. In `ARTICLES` I have **2** columns.

[image]
[image]

Now I want to get the max value of `NRRENDORDOK` column where the `TIP` column has value **'A'**.

e.g. **the max number of cells A in TIP column is 8.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take use of the `MAX` function and then GOUP BY tip in order to get the max value for each `tip`:

```
SELECT tip, MAX(nrreddordok) FROM table GROUP BY tip
```

If you just want values for `A` then you can use following query:

```
SELECT MAX(nrreddordok) FROM table WHERE tip = 'A'
```

Comment: I just want only one. I just want the MAX number of A. I tried you example and it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tip, MAX(nrreddordok) FROM table 
where tip='A'
GROUP BY tip
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL **MAX()** aggregate function

```
select Max(NRRENDORDOK) from table where tip='A'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 nrreddordok
FROM TableName
WHERE Tip = 'A'
ORDER BY nrreddordok DESC
```